# AttributeError: 'EventbriteObject' object has no attribute 'read'

Tags: python, json, api, eventbrite

I'm working with Eventbrite api searching for some events, but at some point im trying to get some attributes out off the response using json.load() but getting this error when trying to print events_load.

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/jo/PycharmProjects/api-eventbrite/api-eventbrite.py", line 21, in <module>
    events_load = json.load(events)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/json/__init__.py", line 265, in load
    return loads(fp.read(),
AttributeError: 'EventbriteObject' object has no attribute 'read'
```

When printing events_dump i can perfectly see the full structure of the json response.

I think im bumping into some internals of python which im not aware off as a beginner.
Can someone point me into a good explanation for this error.
How can i understand what are the attributes and methods a certain object has ?

below the code

```
from eventbrite import Eventbrite

eventbrite = Eventbrite(my_auth_token)

events = eventbrite.get('/events/search/?q=lisboa&categories=102')

# events_dump = json.dumps(events, indent=4)
# print(events_dump)

events_load = json.load(events)
print(events_load)
```

Comment: you forgot to include the error..

Comment: If you can convert `events` to JSON, that means *it is already a Python data structure* and you don't need to use `json.load` on it. Indeed, why would a Python API return something that you needed to process further to actually use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can i understand what are the attributes and methods a certain object has ?

Place `print(dir(eventbrite))` and you will see all the functions and variables in the `Eventbrite` obj.  However I suspect you don't really care about that stuff and you want to see the key/values of the retrieved events.  You can do something like:

```
from eventbrite import Eventbrite

eventbrite = Eventbrite(my_auth_token)
events = eventbrite.get('/events/search/?q=lisboa&categories=102')
for key, val in events.items():
    print('{0}:\t{1}'.format(key,val))
```

There are more elagant ways to do it like `pprint`, but I'll let you figure that out (I've provided the links).  Also, I'd reccomend you start learning how to use Python's debugger `pdb` to help you setup break points and view the values.  Hope that helps.

## Links

- https://docs.python.org/3.2/library/pprint.html
- https://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bZZTeKPRSLQ

Comment: Thanks , this was good materials - also this youtube below gave me some clearance - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Uhm4OlQW7lw

Comment: Also the pdb is nice - although im relying on pycharm debbuger (), but still sometimes a bit confuse with the amount of data insight it gives, not always i understand the info's out of the debugger , for sure it will come with the time :-)

Answer (score 1):

You should include the entire traceback, but I'm pretty sure the error happens here

```
events_load = json.load(events)
```

and the error says that events is an object (`json.load()` takes a file as its argument, which is why the error message says it doesn't have a `.read()` method).

It might be the case that `events` doesn't have a nice printed representation. In that case it's perfectly reasonable to use

```
print(json.dumps(events, indent=4))
```

to print it out nicely formatted.